# fatal .htaccess error

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting

I have a directory for uploaded photos,sorted with date,like this:

```
http://mysite.com/uploads/2012-12-08/abcd.png
```

and I created an `index.php` inside my `/uploads/` folder with a `.htaccess`

I could use the `index.php` to control the image `width` & `height`

the original url looks like this: `http://mysite.com/uploads/?url=2012-12-08/abcd.png&width=128`

here's the `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /uploads/index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and if I enter the url: `http://mysite.com/uploads/2012-12-08/abcd.png&width=128` will appear the resized image

but the issue is the browser display the image extension as `png&width=128`

also the image url cannot be shown in some forum,because the & symbol

how can I change the `.png&width=128` into `.png?width=128?`

there're more that two query string

maximum : ?url=$&width=$&height=$&rotate=$&filter=$&

i have tried the follow rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /uploads/index.php?url=$1&%1 [QSA]
```

but display http error 500

i has tried many rule but no one works..

please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of changing the url to a different pattern. You take the wrong approach. Modern browsers suggest a file name when saving some object downloaded. That file name suggestion is based on the headers specified by the delivering server when the download is requested. The headers carry some additional meta information describing what the actual content is that is sent to the browser.

The url pattern is only used by browsers to suggest a file name when no usable information can be extracted from the headers received.

So what you want to do is to send propper headers, then every browser will use a suggested name. There are many many entries about this if you google for it. As a starting point use this in your index.php script *before* sending the actual image:

```
<?php
// the mime type of the object, replace 'image/png' dynamically as required
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// the suggested file name, obviously you can dynamically replace 'image.png'
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.png'); 
// NOW send the content (the image)
?>
```

As an alternative you can use a different disposition. 'Attachment' forces a download of the image, 'inline' suggests an inline display instead of a download. This will only work if the mime type of the object can actually be displayed inline:

```
<?php
// the mime type of the object, replace 'image/png' dynamically as required
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// the suggested file name, obviously you can dynamically replace 'image.png'
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=image.png'); 
// NOW send the content (the image)
?>
```

Whatever you do, it certainly does make sense to read about how that stuff works and what options and alternatives you have. That is the only way to actually *understand* what is going on, one of the most important things when you implement code. I suggest you start with reading about phps [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Comment: I added this code,but the browser auto downloaded the image,any solution?

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted. The 'Attachment' serves the purpose to force a download. If you want to display the image instead change the header to use 'inline' instead of 'attachment' as shown in the second example.

Comment: but if I use Attachment the first time load the image will show in browser not download,extension still .png&width=xxx.need refresh page to start downloading...

Comment: That you have to refresh the browser is probably a caching effect, nothing you can change about that. It only happens if you had requested the url once before.

Comment: no I changed the width just same...however is it really no anyway to succeed the url like xxx.jpg?width=123?

Comment: I don't understand your issue if the object (image) is shown inside the browser as in the second example: what do you mean by 'extension' in that case?

Comment: extension should be .png,but shown .png&width=256

Comment: I asked before: what 'extension'? It is an image shown inside the browser. There is nothing like a filename in that case. WHERE is that extension?

Comment: okay no extension.no way to solve this with .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry, cannot answer, since there is no question left in my eyes and you fail to express what the issue is.